# onedrive file sync issue and unable install react router dom

Tags: javascript, synchronization, onedrive

[Guys help me with this sink issue. Also im unable to download react router dom in node.js its showing some vulnereabilites , its not fixing even after using suggested commands, is there any issue because of files got manipuleted in node module files. how to fix it, its taking lot of time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSA5o.png)

Guys help me with this sink issue. Also im unable to download react router dom in node.js its showing some vulnereabilites , its not fixing even after using suggested commands, is there any issue because of files got manipuleted in node module files. how to fix it, its taking lot of time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.